# how to get brightness from UIColor correctly?

Tags: objective-c, rgb, uicolor, brightness, hsb

i try to do method which takes B(brightness) from UIColor.

problem is in second part of method. when i log result bri is equal to _red. Where's problem?

```
-(void)rgbToHSBWithR:(float)_red G:(float)_green B:(float)_blue {
_red = _red / 255.0;
_green = _green / 255.0;
_blue = _blue / 255.0;
UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:_red green:_green blue:_blue alpha:1];

float hue, sat, bri, alpha;

[color getHue:&hue saturation:&sat brightness:&bri alpha:&alpha];

NSLog(@"R: %f, G: %0.2f, B: %0.2f, V: %f", _red, _green, _blue, bri);
```

}

Comment: this can happen (and can be correct). what color are you trying to convert and what do you expect to receive?

Comment: in ex. i want to convert 71, 52, 58. when i convert it and bright multiply by 255 i've got: Brightness: 71.  in every case my Brightness is equal to Red.

Comment: when i compare my plot of brightness, is equal to Red plot, so every Brightness = Red. in Photoshop or others app brightness and red plot aren't the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

answer is:

```
    b = (red / 255.0) * 0.3 + (green / 255.0) * 0.59 + (blue / 255.0) * 0.11;
```

it's working fine.

Comment: Nice.  Do you know why you multiple red by .3 and green .59 and blue .11?  Trying to understand how this works.

Comment: It's grayscale values.